# Can you upload an app for iPhone review with data already in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to iPhone development. I realize there are many ways to import data upon the user initially opening an application. However it just seems easier (in the case of my app) to do it manually (through the app's UI in the app simulator) load the data into CoreData myself before it is uploaded to Apple for review. 
A little more background about the app. It is a weight lifting/logging application. I want to "preload", with the method described above, some initial exercises and workout plans to get the user started. 
Is this possible? Or is the data entered in the simulator stored on my local computer only and not in the application package sent to apple upon submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is a file. Its name and location is defined by you when you setup the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

If you are using the Xcode AppDelegate generated template code then its named  after the name of your app `MyApp.sqlite` and lives in the apps Documents folder

You need to populate the database and then copy the file from the simulator folder into your Xcode project. You then need to make sure its one of the bundle assets. It should be by default when you add it to the project.

[image]

When your app first launches you can copy the file from the bundle into the Documents folder of the users local installation.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myApp" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSString *docsfolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *targetpath = [docsfolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dbPath lastPathComponent]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:targetpath error:&error];
```

Don't try and reference the file within the bundle as an active store as you don't get write permission on that file.

You can however setup the persistent store as read only if thats what you want

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options: NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption error:&error]`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Warren (I accepted it) but can you give me a little bit more detail (possibly if it's not too much trouble, how to implement) on your statement: "When your app first launches you can copy the file from the bundle into the Documents folder of the users local installation"?

Comment: see my edit. Its a simple example but you'll want to deal with error cases (like the file is already there)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can copy a bundle SQLite file from your assets to the documents directory on first run, and use the resulting URL as the path for a Core Data store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to upload iphone app with Some data in database

Answer (score 0):

You can do without any problem.
You just have to fill your database and include it in your projet.
Add the code to copy this file to a destination on the device (Ex : Library/Cache folder).

Then use it like if you had a fresh new one.